# In a combination of two vowels (such as "ae"), what rule determines if the first ("a") or second ("e") is silent?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, rules, great-vowel-shift

In a combination of two vowels (such as "ae"), what English rule determines if the first ("a") or second ("e") is silent?

For example, in the word "praetor", the vowel "a" is silent but in the word "maelstrom" the vowel "e" is silent.

Comment: It really doesn’t work that way. You simply have to learn each of them. Most often <ae> becomes `[i:]`, although some people will pronounce it `[eɪ]` as in *maelstrom*, and others occasionally more like `[aɪ]`.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that _praetor_ comes from Latin, and the pronunciation of the word has undergone a lot of changes over time, whereas _maelstrom_ comes ultimately from Dutch and the ae spelling is a way to represent the long a-sound.

Similarly you can find words from German that are, in the absence of umlauts, spelled with an 'e' following the originally umlauted vowel, as in the name Schroeder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment, letters are *never* pronounced. Much rather, it is sounds that are written down. But even that is not entirely true, as written language encodes more than just sound, but also things like etymology, or inflection, that need not be reflected in the pronunciation.

In other words, spoken language is primary; spelling is always an approximation and a compromise.

As a consequence, there is no way to reliably determine pronunciation from spelling. And not just in English using the Latin alphabet, mind you, but in every natural language using whatever writing system.

And don't forget that there are different dialects, too. So there simply is no correct pronunciation of *Mary*, much less *maelstrom*. You have to go with what people around you say. And that is not, and cannot be, reflected in the one single spelling.

A sound can correspond to any number of different spellings, and a letter can correspond to any number of sounds. There is no "rule that determines which letter is silent", because *all* letters are silent by definition. If you want to learn the spoken language, you will have to learn the spoken language. And if you want to learn the currently accepted spelling of a given word, you will have to learn it by heart — just like everybody else, every native speaker, of every language ever.